# Automatically update jQuery DataTables when server-side data changes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to display a web page in a table that should accurately reflect information that is stored on a server. When data on the server changes, the HTML table should update without me having to reload the page.

I understand that I can use [jQuery DataTables with server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) for achieving at least part of this task: an HTML table inside a web page that stays in sync with information stored on a server in the sense that whenever I manipulate the HTML table inside a browser, the server will be contacted for new data using Ajax.

But does DataTables also support changes that are initiated on the server side? For instance, if the server maintains an SQL table and a row is added there, can the HTML table automatically add it as well?

If jQuery DataTables does not support this, is there another plugin or JavaScript/Ajax framework that does? I use Python code for the server part.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for ways to push changes from the sever to client. Have you considered [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)?

Comment: @evenstar I can see how with Firebase jQuery DataTable's model could remain on the client (and Firebase would keep it in sync with a database on the server). What I am wondering whether its model can reside entirely on the server (be it a database or something else). If feasible, I would prefer that as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved on to D3 (tables) in combination with WebSockets and not regretted it: this covers the indicated scenarios and (much) more.